# The maximum file size uploaded using PHP and html5?

Tags: php, html, upload

Any idea on how big the file size could one file uploaded using php and html5?

And

Is there any suggestions on good components or example to do this?

thanks a lot!

Comment: This depends on the settings of the server, but as far as I know apache/php default limit is 8MB

Comment: The only maximum is the one imposed by server configuration.

Comment: You can edit the `max_upload_size` in your php.ini.

Comment: Thanks, I already reset some parameters in the php.ini. And it seems like only 2GB if I use flash to do the uploading...  I may want to upload file more than 5GB.

Comment: @BenLiu any success on finding a TOOL to upload more then 5GB bcz i am also looking for one that can upload file with 2GB+ size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side the maximum upload size is limited by php [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [upload_max_filezize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize).

Also your webserver can limit the maximum size of your post body. E.g. Apache [limitrequestbody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) which defaults to `0 = unlimited` or nginx [client_max_body_size](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) which defaults to `2MB`

If you are planning to upload large files using html5 you might want to have a look at [file.slice](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#) which is supported by all modern browsers

> Support for .slice in the File API
>   Firefox supports the Blob API and the .slice APIs that come with it. This can help people who want to process parts of large File objects from JavaScript without having to load the whole file into the memory. People who reliably upload large files can use some server and JS code to split a large file into sections and upload chunks, including re-retrying failed sections, or even uploading several sections, in parallel.

Using this, you could upload giant files in chunks and merge them on the server-side again.

**EDIT**

Found this great article which explains html5 uploads by streaming via xhr

http://www.webiny.com/blog/2012/05/07/webiny-file-upload-with-html5-and-ajax-using-php-streams/

This procedure has a very low memory footprint, you might still run into the webserver and php upload limits because this is done with a single request. The code should give you an idea on how the whole technology works.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP's pretty crappy when it comes to large file uploads, particularly because you have to a memory limit higher than the size of the file. As well, Apache on 32bit systems tends to have a 2gig file limit itself, so even if PHP could handle the upload, Apache will choke.**

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.

See the [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

The maximum size of an uploaded file is integer.
When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already change these parameters, what I ask is how to upload file more than 5GB using HTML5 and php.

Comment: HTTP is not designed for sending HUGE amounts in a single request. And some servers/clients will choke on it. On apache i think the upper limit is 2GB. And if it messes up half way through, then you get to start over. FTP/SFTP/SCP would be a better tool right tool for the job

Comment: You're probably looking for JUpload : http://jupload.sourceforge.net/ . its java applet that upload huge files

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: http://steffentchr.dk/post/7454042318/resumable-js

Comment: Thanks, I really want to find some HTML5 example for this.

Comment: You said "If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck."

Can't I do this at the top of the script I'm executing?
ini_set("post_max_size", "40M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "40M");

Answer (score 0):

The maximum file size value is defined in phi.ini file.

search this in php.ini

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

upload_max_filesize = 32M